# Express JS - Use of anonymous functions for routes and middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am just getting into Express, and have noticed that every example that I see of routes and middleware is using anonymous functions. Here's an example from the express site:

```
router.get('/user/:id', function(req, res){
  res.send('user ' + req.params.id);
});
```

I'm wondering if there is a reason why I'm not seeing anyone using function declarations instead. Something like this:

```
router.get('/user/:id', getUserById);

function getUserById(req, res) {
  res.send('user ' + req.params.id);
}
```

My question is largely because of my experience with John Papa's angular styleguide. In it, he advises that you use hoisting to your advantage, as laid out here:
https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y053

He essentially advocates for defining your "API" for an angular service at the top, so you can quickly see accessible members of the service without weeding through the implementation. I can see the same potential with routes if you use function declarations. You might have a user route file like this:

```
router.get('/user/:id', getUserById);
router.get('/users', getAllUsers);
router.delete('/user', deleteUser);
router.put('/user/:id', updateUser);

function getUserById(req, res) {
  res.send('user ' + req.params.id);
}

function getAllUsers(req, res) {
  // implement get all users
}

function deleteUser(req, res) {
  // implement delete user
}

function updateUser(req, res) {
  // implement update user
}
```

That way when you're in a view and can't remember exactly what the url needs to be to match a specific route, you can open the users.js file and quickly see all available endpoints right at the top. No scrolling down to find the endpoint you need.

Is there a compelling reason not to do this, or a better way that I'm not seeing?

Comment: No, not really. It's just really easy to create an example that uses an anonymous function. Remember, this is just javascript, the principles that you're used to using still apply.

Comment: This is primarily opinionated. Personally, I prefer to keep my routing functionality separate from my actual routing. So I will used named function references in a different file, using express middleware with `app.use` to apply the router.

Comment: @SterlingArcher You're right, it definitely is about opinion, which is part of why I found it odd that I wasn't seeing anyone sharing how they go about structuring their routes. Appreciate you sharing your thoughts.

Comment: but... the routes are just functions. just like defining event listeners in the browser, all you're doing is adding a callback that will be called at a later date. It doesn't matter if it's an anonymous or named function, all that changes is readability/maintainability/debugability. If you use a named function, you'll get a function name back when tracing an error rather than an anonymous function. If you use a named function, it's easier to reuse and/or export it. but you can do most of those things with anonymous functions too. Which one is better in any given situation is strictly opinion.

Comment: Thanks @KevinB. Those are some of the reasons why I was wondering about this. A function declaration isn't the only way to give it a name, but it has the benefit of letting you put things where they logically make sense. It sounds like the answer is that this is JS, so just treat it as such. No need to get caught up wondering if there is some magical "express way" to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a somewhat MVC style for Express - The way I normally do this is as follows (for an example user API):

Folder layout:

```
app.js
controllers/
    usersController.js
models/
    User.js
routes/
    userRoutes.js
```

app.js

```
var userRoutes = require('./routes/userRoutes')
// Tell express to use the userRoutes for all requests starting'/user'
app.use('/user', userRoutes')
```

/routes/userRoutes.js

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()
var userController = require('../controllers/userController.js')

// localhost:PORT/user
router.get('/', userController.getAll)
router.get('/:id', userController.getById);
```

/controllers/userController.js

```
var User = require('../models/User.js')

exports.getAll = (req, res, next) => {
 // find all users
  User.find({}, ...)
}

exports.getById = (req, res, next) => {
  // req.params.id, then find by ID
}
```

This is just an example, you can use just a single routes file if you prefer, or you can create an object for the userController and then export it if you prefer.

Express gives you great flexibility with how you structure your apps, in the end it's up to what you prefer - there is no 'right' or 'wrong' method.

Comment: Thanks Ashley! It's helpful to see an example of what is working well for someone else. Appreciate you sharing.

Comment: small typo, @ashley; I think your second route should be `router.get('/:id', userController.getById);` in most common uses.

Comment: Glad I could help, I've edited my answer @Paul, thanks for pointing that out.